# How avoid recompile different targets in different paths using autotools?

Tags: release, target, autotools, automake

I already could compile different targets or flavours(debug release), but the problem is when I make: `make debug` or `make release` this generate objects and the library in the respective folder folder.

This is the Makefile.am:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = @AM_CXXFLAGS@

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}

lib_LIBRARIES = libInitDB.a

libInitDB_a_SOURCES = \
InitDB.cpp

.PHONY: debug release

debug:
    make CXXFLAGS='$(CXX_DEBUG_FLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)'
    mkdir -p $(DEBUG_DIR)
    mv $(lib_LIBRARIES) $(DEBUG_DIR)/$(lib_LIBRARIES)
    mv *.o $(DEBUG_DIR)

release:
    make CXXFLAGS='$(CXX_RELEASE_FLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)'
    mkdir -p $(RELEASE_DIR)
    mv $(lib_LIBRARIES) $(RELEASE_DIR)/$(lib_LIBRARIES)
    mv *.o $(RELEASE_DIR)
```

but the problem is when I make: `make debug` or `make release` again, as I move the objects and the library, that generates again the objects and the library that already stored in the debug or release folder.

Could someone help me to find how to avoid this and when I compile that search in the correct folder?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having one `Makefile` generating both flavours of your targets, you could have two separate build directories configured with different options.

For example:

```
mkdir debug
(cd debug && ../configure --enable-debug)

mkdir release
(cd release && ../configure --enable-release)
```

This way, you can go to either directory and recompile only what is needed simply typing `make`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer, but would be possible that make something in the Makefile.am instead to call 2 times to configure.ac?, that would be really helpful for me.

Comment: @arimaujinn No, I don't know of any way to do that and I actually do not want to know. Think about what you want: two different builds of the same sources, using different configuration options, each one with its own intermediate files (*.o) and final targets (libs and executables). This is exactly what build directories are for. Now nothing prevents you to automate the creation/configuration of your build directories using a `Makefile` in a directory above.